# Excel: Generate Index Array for Parent to Child Relationships

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to generate an index for a list of parent to child relationships, delimited per parent. The intention is to create a list that numbers the unique relationships between a parent and child, per parent. An example data set would be:

| Child | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| Child A1 | Parent A |
| Child A2 | Parent A |
| Child A3 | Parent A |
| Child A3 | Parent A |
| Child A2 | Parent A |
| Child A2 | Parent A |
| Child B1 | Parent B |
| Child B1 | Parent B |
| Child B2 | Parent B |
| Child B3 | Parent B |
| Child B2 | Parent B |
| Child B3 | Parent B |

Without using the name of either the parent or child, I am looking to generate the following index:

| Child | Parent | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Child A1 | Parent A | 1 |
| Child A2 | Parent A | 2 |
| Child A3 | Parent A | 3 |
| Child A3 | Parent A | 3 |
| Child A2 | Parent A | 2 |
| Child A2 | Parent A | 2 |
| Child B1 | Parent B | 1 |
| Child B1 | Parent B | 1 |
| Child B2 | Parent B | 2 |
| Child B3 | Parent B | 3 |
| Child B2 | Parent B | 2 |
| Child B3 | Parent B | 3 |

Where the index is a unique value starting, at "1", denoting the individual relationship between a parent an child, per parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=LET(a, A2:A13,
     b, B2:B13,
     c, a&"|"&b,
DROP( REDUCE( HSTACK(@b,@c,1), SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)-1,,2),
      LAMBDA( x,               y,
      VSTACK(x,
             HSTACK(INDEX(b,y),
                    INDEX(c,y),
                    XLOOKUP(INDEX(c,y),
                            INDEX(x,,2),
                            INDEX(x,,3),
                            TAKE(FILTER(INDEX(x,,3),INDEX(x,,1)=INDEX(b,y),0),-1)+1,
                            0,
                            -1))))),
      ,2))
```

[image]

The formula first takes in range `A2:A13` as `a`, `B2:B13` as `b` and the combination of the 2 separated by a `|` is declared as `c`.

Than the REDUCE produces a running array that starts with the initial values of `a`, `b` and value `1`.

**loop start **
From there it starts checking the index of `c` of the following row in the second column of the current calculation result of the formula and returns the value in the matching row, column 3 of the calculation result.
If not found it filters the 3rd column of the calculation result for matching the 1st column of the calc result against the current index of `b` and returns the last value *(or MAX would've worked as well)* and adds one.

The actual result array would looks like this:
[image]

Finally `DROP` removes the first two columns of this array.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=MAP(A2:A13,B2:B13,LAMBDA(c,p,XMATCH(c&"|"&p,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A13,B2:B13=p)&"|"&p))))
```

**Note**: Usually not such a fan of concatenating values, but in this instance I think it can't do any harm.

Comment: Unfortunately its not a mishap, the parent to child relationships can be not sorted in any order due to the data (you can see a similar thing in rows 6 and 7 in your screenshot).

I am looking to generate a unique number for each parent to child relations for a given parent. so in the example above the relationship of "Parent A" to "Child A1" will always generate the value "1" and "Parent A" to "Child A2" will always generate "2" no matter where in the list it is. Continuing, the relationship of "Parent B" to "Child B1" will also always generate the value "1" as this is a new parent.

Comment: @2S2E right, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, XMATCH on the FILTERED uniques. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, long, but it gets the job done:

```
=LET(
    d, A4:B15,
    c, TAKE(d, , 1),
    p, DROP(d, , 1),
    ud, UNIQUE(d),
    uc, TAKE(ud, , 1),
    up, DROP(ud, , 1),
    count, SCAN(0, up = DROP(VSTACK("", up), -1), LAMBDA(a,b, IF(b, a + 1, 1))),
    search, HSTACK(uc & up, count),
    HSTACK(d, XLOOKUP(c & p, TAKE(search, , 1), DROP(search, , 1)))
)
```

[image]